# Concrete Mathematics: Quicksort analysis

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, harmonic-numbers, sorting

I'm trying to work my way through Concrete Mathematics (2nd Edition).

I'm struggling to understand the transition for the analysis of the quick sort algorithm from the *recurrence* to the *harmonic number* representation.

According to the text, the average number of comparison steps made by quicksort can be represented by the following recurrence:

$$C_0 = 0 ;$$
$$nC_n = (n + 1) C_{n-1} + 2n ;\, for\,\, n > 0  $$

Using [2.9] $a_nT_n = b_nT_{n-1} + c_n$, then for this recurrence $a_n=n, b_n=(n+1), c_n=2n$.

The solution to this recurrence can be represented by

$$\
T_n = \frac{1}{s_na_n}\left({s_1b_1T_0} + \sum_{k=1}^ns_kc_k\right) ...[2.10]
$$

Where
$$ s_n = \frac{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}...a_1}{b_nb_{n-1}..b_2} = \frac{2}{(n+1)n}$$

Based on these formulae, the author concludes that 
$$C_n = 2(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+1}$$

I am struggling to understand how $s_kc_k$ can equal $\frac{1}{k+1}$ and not $\frac{4}{k+1}$ because if $s_n=\frac{2}{(n+1)n}$ and $c_n=2n$, then i would expect $s_kc_k$ to equal $\frac{2}{(k+1)k} \times 2k = \frac{4k}{(k+1)k} = \frac{4}{k+1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, But calculate also $\frac{1}{s_n a_n}$ and you will get the expected result when multiplying by your result.

Comment: Ah I'm a twit, need to use the third identity [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/12/) and pull the 4 to the left of the summation and multiply by 1/snan. Thanks @marco